# Beta6 Images in Watch App/Extension

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2

I've got 2 images, with the names: **raccoonInApp**, and **duckInExtension**. The first image resides in the `Assets.xcassets` folder in the **WatchKit App**, and the second image resides in `Assets.xcassets` folder in the **WatchKit Extension**.

I've built an Watch App before earlier in May, so I thought this would be relatively simple. I simply dragged 2 `WKInterfaceController` objects into the storyboard, placed an `WKImageView` in both of them, and using the **attributes inspector** I set the image property to each of the pictures.

Upon running the app, nothing is displayed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the iOS app where the device uses @1x images if @2x / @3x is not available, images in the Apple Watch cannot take the image in the @1x column.